# How to find words in a string according to conditions using for loop or while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing loops with strings for the 1st time and I am wondering if there is a way to write this code but with less instructions.

```
count = 0
str = "flying one plane from one place to the other" \
" but one place is a bit small so we will take one more"
for word in str.split():
    if (word=='one'):
        count+=1
print(count)

for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 1):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()
for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 2):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()

for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 3):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()

for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 4):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()
    
for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 5):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()

for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 6):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()

for word in str.split():
    if (len(word) == 7):
        print(word, end=" ")
print()
```

the output can be in a list or string. it is okay with me. but there must be a cleaner way of writing this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for word in s.split():
    d[len(word)].append(word)
for n in sorted(d):
    print(*d[n])
```

Output:

```
a
to is so we
one one the but one bit one
from will take more
plane place other place small
flying
```

Comment: I like it, also learnt something about defaultdict, thanks for sharing:)

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah true. Thx :)

Comment: awesome, i will look more into the defaultdict and collections. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the words sorted by length, you can do this by using a custom sorting function.

```
s = "flying one plane from one place to the other" \
" but one place is a bit small so we will take one more"

x = s.split()
x.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
```